# Running Java Applet in Fedora

Tags: fedora, java-applet

By default, my browser by default runs java applet in IcedTea application, How to run it through Java system. I am facing some problem with IcedTea. My applet tries to download something but it is not able to do so (as status remains at 0%)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tutorial that describes how to install a newer Java version in Fedora:

http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Install-Java-in-Fedora-Core-6-39724.shtml